# How to toggle css style in google chrome extension(manifest)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this code in manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Simple Css Modification",
  "description": "Simple Css Modification",
  "version": "0.1",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["*://localhost/*"],
  "css": ["style.css"]
  }
  ],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

The styling works fine , just like in style.css.

I don't have any kind of background .js file or any js file in extension folder.
So , my question is , how can i toggle that "style.css" file by clicking the icon ?
I know there is https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction but i don't know how to implement it properly.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple js addition that should get you your basic functionality:

In manifest.json, you can add a javascript file called something like `toggleCss.js`:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://localhost/*"],
    "css": ["style.css"],
    "js": ["toggleCss.js"]
  }
],
```

You will also want to add some configuration for the `browser_action` icon and title (follow the guide you linked, ignoring `default_popup`).

In `toggleCss.js`, add a click handler for the browser action icon, and simply toggle a custom class on the page's `body` element:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    document.body.classList.toggle('customCssClass');
});
```

Then base all of your custom css on a body with that class. Say you want all `spans` to be red:

```
body.customCssClass span {
    color: red;
}
```

Depending on your goals, it might be more performant to toggle classes directly on elements you want to affect using javascript, but using the `body` lets you keep your logic in css, if that's what you prefer.